# Orchard - Querying the Part On A Layout File

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I’ve gotten stuck on an “Object reference not set to an instance of an object” error message.

We’re trying to use a PagePart field that is attached to the Page type to dynamically link a CSS file in the HEAD of a layout file.  See below code.

```
<!-- DYNAMIC CSS-->
var contentItem = Model.ContentItem;
var pagePart = (PagePart)contentItem.PagePart;

if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pagePart.FestivalProgramName))
{
    <link ref="@Url.Content("/Themes/MyTheme/Styles/festival-programs/" + pagePart.FestivalProgramName + ".css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
}
```

This is in a file called:

Layout.cshtml

Something is wrong about this (obviously) since pagePart is “null” when I Attach to Debugger and look.  I get that the Layout file doesn’t know that it’s associated with a “Page” Content Type but this layout is only used with Pages.  Anyway, this is very similar to code that works elsewhere in our Orchard site.  Any help or advice is hugely appreciated!

Thanks, T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Layout, the Model is the Layout object. It has nothing to do whatsoever with whatever content is going to get rendered into the Content zone.

I think what you are trying to do should be done by overriding the Page template (Content-Page.Detail.cshtml). (Note the Detail part, you probably don't want to import every css when displaying multiple pages in summary) 
In there you can do:

```
@{
    var contentItem = Model.ContentItem; // The Page content item
    var pagePart = contentItem.Page; // Note that casting to PagePart won't work, because it does not exist

    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pagePart.FestivalProgramName.Value))
    {
        // "Orchard's" way to include styles
        Style.Include("festival-programs/" + pagePart.FestivalProgramName.Value + ".css");
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

What you probably should do (I assume not every page is a festival page) is create a new Content Type: FestivalPage. Then attach the following parts to this content type (same as the Page content type):

- Common
- Publish later
- Title
- Autoroute
- Body (Orchard 1.8.1 and lower)
- Layout (Orchard 1.9.x)
- Tags
- Localization
- Menu

And your field:

- FestivalProgramName

Then create an alternate Content-FestivalPage.Detail.cshtml with the following content:

```
@using Orchard.Utility.Extensions;
@{
    if (Model.Title != null) {
        Layout.Title = Model.Title;
    }

    Model.Classes.Add("content-item");

    var contentTypeClassName = ((string)Model.ContentItem.ContentType).HtmlClassify();
    Model.Classes.Add(contentTypeClassName);

    var tag = Tag(Model, "article");

    var contentItem = Model.ContentItem; // The FestivalPage content item
    var pagePart = contentItem.FestivalPage; // The FestivalPage part with the FestivalProgramName field

    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pagePart.FestivalProgramName.Value))
    {
        // "Orchard's" way to include styles
        Style.Include("festival-programs/" + pagePart.FestivalProgramName.Value + ".css");
    }
}

// -- Default Orchard content --
@tag.StartElement
    <header>
        @Display(Model.Header)
        @if (Model.Meta != null) {
            <div class="metadata">
                @Display(Model.Meta)
            </div>
        }
    </header>
    @Display(Model.Content)
    @if(Model.Footer != null) {
        <footer>
            @Display(Model.Footer)
        </footer>
    }
@tag.EndElement
// ----
```

This way you won't get in the way with the normal pages of the application.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for responding.  Your solution works but not in my case since I use the Layout Selector module and can't override at the Page.Detail level since that would imply one layout - or at least from my perspective it seems that way.  I found another option though that does the trick.

We already take advantage of the Handlers class to insert META stuff into the HEAD of the page and thanks to your feedback and this thread [Adding an element to page <head> in Orchard CMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012926/adding-an-element-to-page-head-in-orchard-cms), it dawned on me to use the same Handler to insert the CSS link.

PagePartHandler.cs.

```
    using System;
using MyModuleName.Models;
using Orchard.ContentManagement.Handlers;
using Orchard.Core.Title.Models;
using Orchard.Data;
using Orchard.UI.Resources;
using Orchard.Utility.Extensions;

namespace MyModuleName.Handlers {
    public class PagePartHandler : ContentHandler {
        private readonly IResourceManager _resourceManager;

        public PagePartHandler(
            IRepository<PagePartRecord> repository,
            IResourceManager resourceManager) {

            _resourceManager = resourceManager;
            Filters.Add(StorageFilter.For(repository));

            OnGetDisplayShape<PagePart>(RegisterFestivalProgramStyle);
        }

        private void RegisterFestivalProgramStyle(BuildDisplayContext context, PagePart part) {
            if (context.DisplayType != "Detail")
                return;

            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(part.FestivalProgramName))
                return;

            _resourceManager.RegisterLink(new LinkEntry
            {
                Rel = "stylesheet",
                Type = "text/css",
                Href = "/Themes/Bootstrap/Styles/festival-programs/" + part.FestivalProgramName + ".css"
            });
        }
    }
}
```

This uses the tradition link style, not ResourceManifest.cs, but WORKS!